# Storage account connection string does not exist - deploying Queue storage trigger for Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues, queuetrigger

I want to create an azure storage queue triggered azure function. I went through the following tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger

I basically want to trigger the function whenever a message is pushed into the queue and push the result back to another queue once a function is finished.

#### function.json

```js
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "input",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "queue-trigger",
      "connection": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "queue",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "output",
      "queueName": "queue-receiver",
      "connection": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

When i deployed the function, then I am getting the following error in logs present in monitor.
[image]

```js
2022-09-10T12:16:53.412 [Error] The 'QueueTrigger' function is in error: 

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.QueueTrigger'. 

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues: Storage account connection string 'AzureWebJobs<storage account name>_STORAGE' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting.
```

[image]

You can see I have defined, three application settings.

- `AzureWebJobs<storage account>_STORAGE`
- `AzureWebJobsStorage`
- `<storage account>_STORAGE`

According to documentation, if `connection` is empty in function.json then **AzureWebJobsStorage** will be used.

Even i tried to set `connection:"<storage account>_STORAGE"`, that also raised the same error.

Comment: As you left the `connection` property empty, have you set the value of AzureWebJobsStorage to point to the queue's conn string ?

Comment: I assume in the actual deployed function, `connection` is explicitly set to `"AzureWebJobs<storage account>_STORAGE"` in your function.json file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment, and the below workaround worked for me:

I have created a storage account and copied the connection as below and i created a queue too over there as below
[image]

Then i pasted it in local.settings file in vs studio as below:

[image]

And now i published it too azure.
Click on App setting in Configuration , if Connection string name is present then open that and paste the connection string.
If not Then in published function app i created a connection string in application settings and copied the same connection string that i have taken from Storage account
[image]

[image]
Then click on ok then save it.
Then send message in queue as below:
[image]
And this workaround worked for me.