# How to set value for EventHub and AzureWebJobsStorage

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have created an event hub and storage account in the Azure portal and written an azure function with an eventhub trigger to trigger the function.

To run this function locally, I set the "AzureWebJobsStorage" and "EventHubconnectionstring" in local.settings.json and this works fine.

If I deploy this function to azure portal, how can I set this "EventHubconnectionstring" and "AzureWebJobsStorage" values ? does it picked up automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deploy it from Visual Studio the values become null. Then you need to open Configuration section in function app and enter those values there as below:

[image]

[image]

If you deploy using Vs code the values will be reflected in configuration section.
If you face the issue as empty connection string, then you need to add it in Configuration section then save it.And you should do the same for event hub connection string.

**References:**

- [Storage account connection string does not exist - deploying Queue storage trigger for Azure Functions - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73673431/storage-account-connection-string-does-not-exist-deploying-queue-storage-trigg/73681053#73681053)